# Add table inside plot Julia

Tags: plot, julia, julia-plots

I have the following bar plot:

```
using Plots, DataFrames

Plots.bar(["A", "B", "c"],[6,5,3],fillcolor=[:red,:green,:blue], legend = :none)
```

Output:

[image]

I would like to add a simple small table inside to plot in the top right corner. The table should have the following values of the dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame(x = ["A", "B", "c"], y = [6,5,3])

3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x       y     
     │ String  Int64 
─────┼───────────────
   1 │ A           6
   2 │ B           5
   3 │ c           3
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add a simple table to a `Plots` graph in Julia?

Comment: Do you mean attaching the table with its format to the picture using a snippet?? Why? What is the reason behind it? using [photoshop](https://www.photopea.com/) wouldn't be easier?

Comment: Hi @Shayan, I don't know what the possibilities are with Plots, but I would like to have a small table like the dataframe (without 3x2 DataFrame, Row, String, Int64 elements) to show the values in a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
using Plots, DataFrames

df = DataFrame(; x=["A", "B", "c"], y=[6, 5, 3])
plt = Plots.bar(
    df[!, :x], df[!, :y]; fillcolor=[:red, :green, :blue], legend=:none, dpi=300
)
Plots.annotate!(
    1,
    4,
    Plots.text(
        replace(string(df), ' ' => '\u00A0'); family="Courier", halign=:left, color="black"
    ),
)

Plots.savefig("plot.svg")
```

Which gets you the following plot (after conversion to PNG for uploading to StackOverflow):

[image: Plot]

Note that we have to replace space characters with `'\u00a0'`, non-breaking space, to prevent multiple consecutive spaces from being collapsed by the SVG (SVG‘s collapse consecutive spaces by default).